# error while loading shared libraries: libcapnp-0.5.3.so

Tags: c++, linux, protocol-buffers, capnproto

I think this is a generic problem not specifically related to Cap'n Proto.

My project's build succeeds but on run I get:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcapnp-0.5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Maybe I am missing something in CMake?

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lcapnp -lkj")
```

I verified `libcapnp-0.5.3.so` exists in `/usr/local/lib`

I also tried adding:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -L/usr/local/lib/libcapnp-0.5.3.so")
```

Comment: i am not sure. did you try to make a symbolic link to it and name it `libcapnp.so`?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr When I run `ls -l` in `/usr/local/lib` I see that `libcapnp.so -> libcapnp-0.5.3.so`  so I guess this has already been done by the installer.

Comment: another explanation is this folder is not in the search path of rt linker.

Comment: `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` what do you have?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr nothing is there... should I add `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Erm.. no, he should not. That's the nuclear option.

Comment: @Pradhan i think it's ok. since op is in dev env and doing this helps to try out where the problem locates. it's bad only if, say, an installer silently exports this variable to environment and put it somewhere in autorun script.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Added it to `LB_LIBRARY_PATH` and restarted (because it wasn't working) but it disappeared.  Researching this now.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr If you are suggesting that he use it as a quick check to ascertain the viability of his `libcapnp.so`, yes, that isn't a problem. For the OP's benefit, please note that you almost never want to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as the final solution - see [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Comment: Got it working, thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @BAR no restart is required. I take that as not working too?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I had not run `ldconfig` so that is probably why it did not work.

Comment: If that's the problem after setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH you should see your program working. That's a little bit weird. Anyways, good to know problem solved.

Comment: @Pradhan Agreed. But nonetheless it's very convenient probe with little side effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/local/lib` needs to be added to `/etc/ld.so.conf`

then run `sudo ldconfig` to load the changes.